# relaying data from a web service to other computers

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

My team has been assigned a java spring Project in which we get some data from a soap web service. Only certain IP addresses can access the service (in our case, test and prod servers)

But we'd like to be able to access the service from our local computers to be able to debug and such. What would be a simple workaround to achieve this?

Comment: A simple workaround would be a vpn

Comment: ssh tunneling. ssh from a local computer to one of the computers that can reach it, and tunnel the port through to the remote host.